# print web page in different print quality width fix element size, mozilla, dot matrix printer

Tags: html, css, firefox, printing, dot-matrix

I am having problems with printing in dot matrix printer.
My client printer is Epson LX300+II and Epson LQ-2170.
I need to print from a web apps that written in php. with web browser client is Mozilla Firefox
But i can't set the fix width for the layout.
for example:

```
<div style="width:2in">
content
</div>
```

when i print those things, different print quality produce different size of printed content
using LX300+II, print quality 120x72 dpi the 2in will be printed around 1,7in
using LX300+II, print quality 120x144 dpi the 2in will be printed around 3in
how am I able to create a fix layout in html to be print in different print quality because my client using 2or 3 different printer to print the form.

Comment: I get this problems when using mozilla
Try to print using IE and have no problems with it

Comment: After check it again, in IE and in Opera it print correctly, in Mozilla only properties 'height' will print correctly. But properties width not print correctly (the length of the width not 2in)

Answer (score 0):

printing always seems to be a problem with browsers not to mention that browsers tend to add their own headers and footer (unless the user is clever enough to know how to switch this off). I have found the best way around this is to create a PDF document which the client can view and print when they want.